# IS NULL not working in where clause when this data is imported from text file into SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

I converted an Excel file into a text file, then imported this text file into a SQL Server database using the SQL Server import/export wizard tool. I found `IS NULL` not working in the `where` clause on one column (see the following):

```
WHERE ID IS NULL;
```

BTW, `ID` column's data type is `varchar(50)` with `null` as the default.

Does anybody have any idea why `IS NULL` does not work here?

Comment: Try a `select *` without the where condition to see if there are any values that are null.  It is possible that there just aren't any null values.

Comment: What exaclty do you mean by "does not work"? Does it always return `false`?

Answer (score 1):

The import probably loaded the values as empty strings into of as `NULL`.  To handle this, change `WHERE ID IS NULL` to `WHERE ID = ''`

If you want them to be `NULL`, you can change them:

```
UPDATE Your_Table SET ID = NULL WHERE ID = ''
```

Answer (score 1):

David's answer is most likely what you need, but for completeness... Are the values truly `NULL` or are they `'null'` ?

Test:

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM TABLE WHERE ID IS NULL
```

Test:

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM TABLE WHERE ID='null'
```

If the latter returns results, then the string `'null'` was stored, not an actual absent/`NULL` value.

You can set them to `NULL` as follows:

```
UPDATE T
SET ID=NULL
FROM TABLE T
WHERE ID='null'
```

If neither returned data, then find what is there... maybe they're all legit values.

```
SELECT COUNT(2), ID
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID
--HAVING COUNT(2)>1 /* uncomment this line if too much comes back... */
```

Then decide how to proceed...